# angularjs can't find the html using data-ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to develop an application using angularjs+mvc+api.as you can see here my angular js module and controller :

```
//home-index.js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.config([function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        Controller: "homeIndexController",
        templateUrl:"templates/t.html"

    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise("/");
}]);
myApp.controller('homeIndexController', homeIndexController);
function homeIndexController($scope,$http) {
       $scope.data2 = [];
    $scope.busy = true;
    $http.get("/api/default").
        then(function(result) {
            //success
            angular.copy(result.data, $scope.data2);
        }, function() {
            //error
        }).then(function() {
            $scope.busy = false;
        });
}
```

As you can i create a routing .so if the user enter this url `http://localhost:20713/Home/Index/#/` the angular should load the `t.html` in my templates folder .

I have a view that the t.html should be injected to it ,as you can see here :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

here is the content of t.html file :

```
Hi this is a test
```

But when i call this url `http://localhost:20713/Home/Index/#/` nothing happens!!and the page is empty and the message `Hi this is a test` doesn't exist in it .why ?

The resource of my page in the browser

[image]

Comment: Did you specify ng-app directive on your index file?

Comment: @codeninja.sj I have this in my layout <html data-ng-app="myApp">

Comment: @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div data-ng-view=""></div> _____this is my index content

Comment: @codeninja.sj in console of browser i get this error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=TypeError%…ee%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A20713%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A156)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the  reference of angular js

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

and every thing works fine .why ?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892299/is-difference-between-local-install-or-reference-url-of-angular-js#

Answer (score 0):

Inject *ngRoute* module on your *myApp* module

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

And specify array inline annotations properly

```
myApp.config('$routeProvider', [function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        Controller: "homeIndexController",
        templateUrl:"templates/t.html"

    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise("/");
}]);
```

Comment: same error:Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=TypeError%…ee%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A20713%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A156)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:40q @ angular.min.js:7g @ angular.min.js:39bb @ angular.min.js:43c @ angular.min.js:21yc @ angular.min.js:21ee @ angular.min.js:20(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:313c @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21p.fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21x.extend.ready @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21q @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21

Comment: Did you include **angular-route.js** file on your layout?

Comment: Your error message clearly shows that you forgot to include the required module. In your case, you are already included the 'ngRoute' module. Please check if you missed, any other required module.

Comment: i added a picture the resource of my page in browser ,could you please take a look?

Comment: I have seen your image but its not enough to fix your problem; Error message clearly shows that problem is on injecting module(s). Use **angular.js** file instead of ***.min.js** file; you will get more detailed error message

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

and also change

```
Controller: "homeIndexController"
```

to

```
controller: "homeIndexController",
```

Comment: I just test it. 100% its `Controller` letter size. It just show blank page otherwise :)