# is difference between local install or reference url of angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to develop an application using angular js .it a simple routing .when i add the angular by url like this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

My application works fine ,but when i add like this :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
```

I got this error :

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module sampleApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvide
```

Here is my app.js

```
//Define an angular module for our app
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

//Define Routing for app
//Uri /AddNewOrder -> template add_order.html and Controller AddOrderController
//Uri /ShowOrders -> template show_orders.html and Controller AddOrderController
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/AddNewOrder', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/add_order.html',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        }).
        when('/ShowOrders', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
            controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/AddNewOrder'
        });
  }]);


sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';

});


sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';

});
```

Here is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="sampleApp">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is located there. What does the network panel show?

Comment: @epascarello yes the file is there ,i installed that by nuget in vs

Comment: @epascarello in the network all files are available

Comment: @Ehsan Akbar: do you get any 404 error in your developer console, before  the `[$injector:unpr]` error?

Comment: @MarcoS no i don't

Comment: You forgot a final 'r' in the error you did post, or is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add the reference to the module (angular route module) that your module is dependent on. The error says that $routeProvide is unknown to it and that is available in the angular route module.

```
//Define an angular module for our app
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: I added your answer but i get this errors:Uncaught Error: No module: ngRoute and Uncaught TypeError: window.angular.$$csp is not a function
angular.min.js:17 Uncaught Error: No module: ngRoute

Comment: That means the file angular-route.min.js is not getting loaded. Check out your reference and/or with the browser developer tools as to why this .js file is missing.